# Photoshop Holographic textures

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture, mockup

I am trying to create chrome/holographic sticker mockup with photoshop. I came across some tutorial for liquid iridescent textures but it wasn't what I was looking for.
I'd really like to create a mockup like this:

[image]

which is not just a "liquid holographic texture" but a sort of chrome background with rainbow shades, that seems more like a cd texture.
Has someone already done something like this before? Can someone give me some advice?

EDIT:
The final result i'd like to have is something pretty similar to this

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I achieve an iridescent/metallic/holographic effect in raster editors?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/120757/how-can-i-achieve-an-iridescent-metallic-holographic-effect-in-raster-editors)

Comment: Thank you! I've just made some changes at the question

Comment: Your new examples look cool! In a way it's the same as the question I marked as duplicate, but one of the things that looks different in your examples is that the surface texture of the material is very visible. So it's a combination of the "rainbow effect" and a "dented surface effect". Do you want to reproduce both effects?

Comment: Yes because it should be something like the holographic sticker on this two images:
https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/673428950512788327/?nic=1
https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/690035974140674432/?nic=1

Answer (score 3):

It's like some color lights seen as reflected by a little worn aluminium foil paper or cardboard. Here's at first an attempt to synthesize something resembling:

For a start paint some colors which together fill a layer totally:

[image]

Then apply a heavy Gaussian blur:

[image]

As you see the blurring reduces fully black, white and all original color areas, have them as large enough to compensate beforehand if the original color must be seen.

To distort it you need some displacement.A contrast boosted photo of foil paper could be used as a displacement map in Photoshop. I haven't such photo, so I inserted filter Ocean Ripple:

[image]

Try also Filter > Distort > Glass.

For more effect you can add an embossed photo of some scratches. I used this, it presented originally surface damages, but here it has got Photoshop's embossing filter:

[image]

With blending mode Hard light it gives this:

[image]

If you want something more realistic, get a real piece of metallized paper or cardboard, something like this:

[image]

Take a photo of a computer screen image which is reflected by the metal. Prepare some colorful image for the shot. Focus your camera to the metal. If you watch carefully your 2 last examples, you will see they use the same metallized surface.

As already said, you can also use metallized paper texture as a displacement map in Photoshops Distort > Displace -effect and you can extract some dimples and scratches with embossing from a surface image.

Comment: +1 I like this! The scratches are a little too visible for my taste. And the ripples are different from the original because they only darken what's beneath. In the original the ripples seems to be colored by the adjacent colors. Hard to explain. Anyway I can't figure out a better way than what you did here.

Comment: @Wolff Ocean Ripple works as you wanted, it moves portions forth and back over the borderline between different colors. Here's no borderlines, the gradient makes the effect subtle, but it's there. About scratches: I didn't have a photo which has fine scratches + a few dimples. The visibility can be reduced by reducing the layer opacity.

Comment: I guess you're right. Anyway, it looks good.